# pip installing eyeD3 module. Failed to find libmagic

Tags: python, pip

Trying to install eyed3 but it's giving me this error:

```
>>> import eyed3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    import eyed3
  File "C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\eyed3\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .utils.log import log                                            # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\eyed3\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    import magic
  File "C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\magic.py", line 176, in <module>
    raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation
```

Here's the pip install:
[image: pip install]

I tried to uninstall with pip and delete all the eyed3 files, then re-install and it still gave the same error. It also does the same thing with easy_install.

Answer (score 22):

**On Windows**

You'll need DLLs for libmagic. @julian-r has uploaded a version of this project that includes binaries to pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic-bin/0.4.14

```
pip install python-magic-bin==0.4.14
```

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me :)

Comment: If by default you install `python-magic` using pip, it would install the latest version= 0.4.15 which does not have the DLLs required for it to work, but the version=0.4.14 has those DLLs. Its better to install this version than the latest one.

Comment: Thanks, I never red the eyed3 docs, this saved me a lot of time. :-)

Comment: Worked on my Mac as well. :)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by installing libmagic with this command
 `brew install libmagic`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install libmagic before you install eye3d.

Here is a link to the  git.
https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic#dependencies

You can use this to install it:

```
pip install python-magic
```

Comment: I have same problem. I install python magic but still `ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation`

Comment: @Mostafa Any luck on your end?

Comment: I already had it, after i tried this, thanks though.  Apparently @acid magic solution worked.