# ImportError (libmagic) when using eyed3 module

Tags: python, python-3.x, eyed3, libmagic

Am a newbie to Python and is trying to use eyed3 module. Here is my code.

```
import eyed3

def GetAlbumName(filename):
    tag = eyed3.tag()
```

I am running into exception

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError failed to find libmagic
```

As explained in the following link, I installed "python-magic", but the exception still remains.
[pip installing eyeD3 module. Failed to find libmagic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518690/pip-installing-eyed3-module-failed-to-find-libmagic)

Within Visual Studio Code, I tried changing the interpeter (Ctrl+Shift+P), but that didn't help either

Comment: What OS are you using?  Sometimes libmagic requires a specific `.whl` file depending on your os.

Answer (score 0):

### On Windows

Run `pip install python-magic-bin` to import the required DLL's for libmagic.

---

### On OSX

Run `brew install libmagic` if you're using homebrew or `port install file` if you're using macport

---

It's all included in the Installation section of the python-magic repo https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic